# Render to texture, but how to save it with transparency using DirectX?

Tags: directx, png, transparency, render-to-texture

I'm using DirectX 11 SDK and render something to the texture (and it's works). Than use D3DX11SaveTextureToFile to save the output to the PNG texture. Everything works, but I don't get transparency.

**I want to have the background** (space where none of the elements have been rendered) **transparent**. Instead of this, I get some background.

I was trying to change the `float ClearColor[4]` for the `ClearRenderTargetView` function to the`{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }` because I thought that last one is alpha and **1.0f** with give me transparency, but that haven't worked for me (**the same for 0.0f**).

Here is the part of my code that may be useful:

Blend states (which I believe are good, they works for rendering transparent elements on screen - of course screen of monitor always have some "background", the PNG file not):

```
D3D11_BLEND_DESC blendDesc;
ZeroMemory(&blendDesc, sizeof(D3D11_BLEND_DESC) );
blendDesc.AlphaToCoverageEnable = false;
blendDesc.IndependentBlendEnable = false;        
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendEnable = true;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlend = D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlend = D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOp = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;

blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].SrcBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO; 
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].DestBlendAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_ZERO; 
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].BlendOpAlpha = D3D11_BLEND_OP_ADD;
blendDesc.RenderTarget[0].RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D11_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL ;

ID3D11BlendState * blendState;

if(FAILED(device->CreateBlendState(&blendDesc, &blendState))){
        //...
}

g_pImmediateContext->OMSetBlendState(blendState,NULL,0xffffffff);
```

And:

```
// Setup the render target texture description.
textureDesc.Width = textureWidth;
textureDesc.Height = textureHeight;
textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
textureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;    
...
//Create the render target texture.
result = device->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &renderTargetTexture);  
...
result = device->CreateShaderResourceView(renderTargetTexture, 
    &shaderResourceViewDesc, &shaderResourceView);  
...
g_pImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &renderTargetView, 
    g_pDepthStencilView);
float ClearColor[4] = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f }; //red, green, blue, alpha
g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView( renderTargetView, ClearColor );

//clear the depth buffer to 1.0 (max depth)
g_pImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView( g_pDepthStencilView, 
    D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0 ); 
...
//render here
...
D3DX11SaveTextureToFile(g_pImmediateContext, renderTargetTexture, 
    D3DX11_IFF_BMP, CommonFunctions::s2ws(newTextureName).c_str());
```

Comment: The alpha works the other way round. 0.0f stands for full transparent, 1.0f is full visible. (alpha-value = opacity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save a PNG file, use `D3DX11_IFF_PNG` instead of `D3DX11_IFF_BMP`.

---

As PolGraphic mentioned in his comment, it might be necessary to change the blend state from  D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA and D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA to D3D11_BLEND_ONE which works for PNG. However, in most cases the default setting SRC_ALPHA / INV_SRC_ALPHA should work.

Comment: I have tried it, but than I don't get my image at all. Only a black rectangle on the half of the image and transparent background. What is even more strange, the rectangle occurs where there should be a transparent background (no elements), and the transparent is where there are objects.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct blend states? And make sure to clear to (0,0,0,0).

Comment: Thanks about blend states. Changing from D3D11_BLEND_SRC_ALPHA and D3D11_BLEND_INV_SRC_ALPHA to D3D11_BLEND_ONE works for PNG! But in the scene I get semi-transparent all objects. Don't sure why, but I have to use different blend states for rendering to PNG and scene. Can you edit your anserw and place there information about blend states? It will be more clear for readers, because the final anserw is partly in the comment now ;-)